# Debugging a JSON decoder

Tags: elm

I'm trying to test a decoder - but I only ever get back the default values. Apologies for the wall of text, but when I've tried smaller examples, they always work, so I'm guessing there's a stupid error in here somewhere.

I've been trying to figure out why this won't work for quite a while now, with no luck. The JSON appears to be valid (I have tried parsing it in JS and in online validators).

I've tried different methods of decoding the JSON, again with no luck.

Any help **at all** is very much appreciated. If anything else should be added to the question, please let me know (I'm new to elm, if you can't tell).

I'm trying to decode JSON which looks like this:

```json
                        {
                            "fade": 1,
                            "colour": "Campbells Red",
                            "stock": 1,
                            "site": "",
                            "url": "",
                            "plastic":"DX",
                            "name":"aviar",
                            "seenAt":1612884837886,
                            "weight":175,
                            "compositeIdentifier":"aviar||Innova||DX||Campbells Red||175",
                            "manufacturer":"Innova",
                            "expiresAt":1615476837886,
                            "glide":3,
                            "turn":0,
                            "speed":2,
                            "price":8.99
}
```

My type looks like this:

```
type alias DiscSighting =
    { fade: Int
    , colour: String
    , stock: Int
    , site: String
    , url: String
    , plastic: String
    , name: String
    , weight: Int
    , compositeIdentifier: String
    , manufacturer: String
    , glide: Int
    , turn: Int
    , speed: Int
    , price: Float
    }
```

And my decoder looks like this:

```
discDecoder: Decoder DiscSighting
discDecoder =
    succeed DiscSighting
        |> andMap (field "fade" (int) |> (withDefault) -1)
        |> andMap (field "colour" (string) |> (withDefault) "")
        |> andMap (field "stock" (int) |> (withDefault) -1)
        |> andMap (field "site" (string) |> (withDefault) "")
        |> andMap (field "url" (string) |> (withDefault) "")
        |> andMap (field "plastic" (string) |> (withDefault) "")
        |> andMap (field "name" (string) |> (withDefault) "")
        |> andMap (field "weight" (int) |> (withDefault) -1)
        |> andMap (field "compositeIdentifier" (string) |> (withDefault) "")
        |> andMap (field "manufacturer" (string) |> (withDefault) "")
        |> andMap (field "glide" (int) |> (withDefault) -1)
        |> andMap (field "turn" (int) |> (withDefault) -1)
        |> andMap (field "speed" (int) |> (withDefault) -1)
        |> andMap (field "price" (float) |> (withDefault) -1)
```

The error I get is due to a test failing (it returns the error side of the result and thus fails the test):

> Err (Failure "Expecting an OBJECT with a field named `price`
> )

Comment: What are your definitions for `andMap` and `withDefault`? Are you using [Json.Decode.Extra](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/json-extra/latest/Json-Decode-Extra)? 
Try removing one of the `withDefault`s and see what error it gives.

Comment: @absynce they come from Json.Decode.Extra, sorry, I ought to have said. When I remove `withDefault` I get an error, rather than the Ok response. The answer below seems to be able to decode the object, but when I use the same code, it isn't able to decode the JSON string as I have it

Comment: Could you add the details of the error response to your question?

Comment: I've added it now (but I'm guessing it's not too useful)

Comment: @absynce turns out I was using the wrong variable... can't believe it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `discDecoder` I'm not sure what the definitions are for `andMap` and `withDefault`, but the [optional](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/NoRedInk/elm-json-decode-pipeline/latest/Json-Decode-Pipeline#optional) function in the package [NoRedInk/elm-json-decode-pipeline](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/NoRedInk/elm-json-decode-pipeline/latest/) will work instead of `andMap` and `withDefault`:

```
discDecoder : Decoder DiscSighting
discDecoder =
    succeed DiscSighting
        |> optional "fade" int -1
        |> optional "colour" string ""
        |> optional "stock" int -1
        |> optional "site" string ""
        |> optional "url" string ""
        |> optional "plastic" string ""
        |> optional "name" string ""
        |> optional "weight" int -1
        |> optional "compositeIdentifier" string ""
        |> optional "manufacturer" string ""
        |> optional "glide" int -1
        |> optional "turn" int -1
        |> optional "speed" int -1
        |> optional "price" float -1
```

Full working example here: https://ellie-app.com/ckYm8HhMJfKa1

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I tried this on my code, and whilst I can see that it can decode `data` as an object, I'm confused as to how it should be used to decode a json string. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I was making maybe the dumbest error so far and pointing this at the wrong variable the entire time... thank you for pointing me in the right direction and showing me that what I hvae REALLY ought to work... provided I use the right input!

Comment: @OliverRadini I'm glad you got it to work!